# How do Create a Checkbox Element in WPF with Image and Some Text

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I want to design a Control Similar to this, where to the left corner would be Some Text and right corner will have Checkbox mark.

I tried doing something like this.

```
        <ListView x:Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="DoubleLineDataTemplate" >
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Img}">
                        </Image>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

But the output isn't what I want.

[image: Requirement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put Image, text and checkbox in a single Grid and stick text and checkbox to corners:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Name="DoubleLineDataTemplate" >
          <Grid>
            <Image VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Img}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5"/>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5"/>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Also, What is the Cleanest way to get all the checked Items?

Comment: @AkshayBheda, iterate ItemsSource collection and take all elements with property IsChecked equal to true: `var selected = MyCollection.Where(x => x.IsChecked).ToList();`. if you don't have itemssource, iterate MyListView.Items